# animate an item from fragment adapter to its parent activity

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a layout like this :

[image]

I have activity, inside of activity is a fragment and a box, inside of the fragment is a recyclerview (ex. list of song title and image)

Activity -> Fragment -> RecyclerViewAdapter

I'm using this animation, it is working well but the problem is the
**animation moves only inside the fragment area**. (based on the pic I want it to animate an item from recyclerview going to the box)

```
   holder.rl_main_layout.animate().x(xValue).y(yValue);
```

so can anyone suggest an Idea to do what I want?

Comment: You can start from here: https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/index.html

Answer (score 1):

**Fly item from recycler view to cart icon on toolbar**

**Please check this link , this will guide you how you can accomplish your problem**

[Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44085260/932219)
[image]